# Post запрос используя retrofit

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, httpurlconnection

Нужно создать POST запрос с отправкой логина,пароля и получением токена, мне порекомендовали retrofit, так как стандартными способами это не получается сделать. Но я не понимаю как в нем создается запрос (документацию смотрел), к примеру

```
public interface API { 
   @POST("/v1/registration") 
   Response registerUser(); 
}
```

Но я не понимаю как минимум , где ссылка на сайт и где задаются параметры запроса. Тут я вижу запрос на регистрацию пользователя, но где все данные? он берет их из метода?

UPD:

```
   public interface API {
    @POST("/v1/registration")
    Response registerUser(@Body RegistrationBody registrationBody);
    Call<RegistrationResponse> registerUser();
}
public class RegistrationBody{
    public String login;
    public String password;
}
public class RegistrationResponse {
    public String token;
}
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://myserver1.com")
        .build();
API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
@POST("/v1/registration")
Call<RegistrationResponse> registerUser(@Body RegistrationBody registrationBody) {
    return null;
}
Call<RegistrationResponse> call = api.registerUser();
call.enqueue(new Callback<RegistrationResponse() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<RegistrationResponse> response) {
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            // tasks available
        } else {
            // error response, no access to resource?
        }
    }
```

есть ошибки начиная с call.enqueue

Comment: Для начала метод ```Call<RegistrationResponse> registerUser()``` должен быть точно таким же, как и обычный за исключением возвращаемого параметра.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Например у нас есть сервер с POST методом регистрации - `https://myserver1.com/v1/registration`

Например данный метод принимает Json вида:

```
{
  "logins": "ttt",
  "password": "123"
}
```

и возвращает ответ вида

```
{
    "token":"someToken"
}
```

Тогда в проекте надо определить интерфейс, описывающий данный метод сервера таким образом

```
public interface API { 
   @POST("/v1/registration") 
   RegistrationResponse registerUser(@Body RegistrationBody registrationBody); 
}
```

Где RegistrationBody и RegistrationResponse это классы со следующими полями:

```
public class RegistrationBody{
    public String login;
    public String password;
}

public class RegistrationResponse {
    public String token;
}
```

Далее для обращения к серверу сначала необходимо создать объект `Retrofit` куда необходимо передать имя сервера и любую другую дополнительную информацию.

```
Retrofit retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://myserver1.com")
                .build();
```

После, из этого объекта можно получить реализацию интерфейса с методами

```
API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
```

Ну и далее у объекта `api` вызывать нужные методы. Только помните, что нельзя лезть в интернет в основном потоке. Что бы вынести обращение к серверу в отдельный поток можно воспользоваться средствами, которые предоставляет Retrofit. Для этого надо в интерфейсе возвращаемый параметр обернуть в тип `Call`

```
@POST("/v1/registration") 
Call<RegistrationResponse> registerUser(@Body RegistrationBody registrationBody);
```

и потом вызвать

```
Call<RegistrationResponse> call = api.registerUser(...);
call.enqueue(new Callback<RegistrationResponse() {  
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<RegistrationResponse> response) {
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            // tasks available
        } else {
            // error response, no access to resource?
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
    }
}
```

UPD:
В метод `api.registerUser(...)` необходимо передать объект `RegistrationBody` предварительно заполнив его данными:

```
RegistrationBody body = new RegistrationBody();
body.login = "myLogin";
body.password = "12345";

api.registerUser(body);
```

Сериализация происходит с использованием библиотеки GSON, как правильно сериализовать объект, читайте в [официальной документации](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md).

Для работы в асинхронном режиме просто в интерфейсе `API` создайте метод, который будет возвращать `Call<T>` вместо `T`

Comment: Спасибо большое, за такой подробный ответ. Но я немного не понял 2 моментов. Когда создаем второй поток, мне нужно интерфейс API переопределить или создать новый интерфейс? а второй вопрос, что мне вписывать в api.registerUser(...), переменные логин и пароль?

Comment: @SlavaNenashev дополнил ответ

Comment: Теперь хочет что бы я изменил на response в последней строчке.
 API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
    RegistrationBody body = new RegistrationBody();
    @POST("/v1/registration")
    Call<RegistrationResponse> registerUser(@Body RegistrationBody registrationBody) {
        body.login = "myLogin";
        body.password = "12345";
        api.registerUser(body);
        return null;
    }

    Call<RegistrationResponse> call = api.registerUser(body);

Comment: @SlavaNenashev Функция ```Call<RegistrationResponse> registerUser(...)``` нужно только написать в интерфейсе, вам самому ничего не надо реализовывать, а только получить реализацию ```API``` через метод ```retrofit.create(API.class)``` и вызывать у него нужные методы. Смотрите внимательней мои примеры и примеры на сайте Retrofit'a.