# Получение токена android. POST, GET Retrofit 2

Tags: android, api, post, get, retrofit

Возможно я задам не самый умный вопрос, но я новичок в разработке под android. 
Проблема заключается в следующем, что мне нужно получить токен. И этот токен далее прикладывать к get запросам. API key есть, но я не понимаю как его прикладывать. 
В документации указано следующее:

> POST api/v1.1/authenticate
>   Отвечает на POST запрос, в котором содержится заголовок Authorization: Basic {ApiKey}.
>   Ключ API для вашего приложения (ApiKey) можно взять на странице приложения.

И далее после получения токена мне нужно сделать такой запрос:

> GET api/v1/Translation?text={text}&srcLang={srcLang}&dstLang={dstLang}&isCaseSensitive={isCaseSensitive}
>   Словарный перевод слова/фразы. Поиск осуществляется только в указанном направлении.
>   Требует HTTP-заголовок с токеном авторизации: "Authorization: Bearer {token}".
>   См. справку по методу /api/v1/authenticate.

[Документация](https://developers.lingvolive.com/ru-ru/Help).

Comment: вы как-то аутентификацию уже сделали или это непонятно тоже?

Comment: И это тоже непонятно. Дело в том, что вроде понимаю как все устроено, но только теоретически...может ткнете меня куда читать/смотреть?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494099/post-запрос-используя-retrofit - вот например

Comment: Спасибо. Буду разбираться и пробовать.

Comment: И ещё не совсем понятно, где указать заголовок Authorization: Basic {ApiKey}

Comment: это я думаю будет указываться уже после того как вы получите токен, и дальше вам нужно будет получать информацию используя токен в запросе

Comment: Как написано в документации POST api/v1.1/authenticate Отвечает на POST запрос, в котором содержится заголовок Authorization: Basic {ApiKey}. Поэтому мне и непонятно, каким образом указывать это.

Comment: у вас должен быть запрос post в который вы кладете ваши например юзернейм и пароль, а сервер в ответ должен вернуть три вещи - рефреш токен, акцесс токен и время когда протухнет акцесс токен. По логике должно быть так

Comment: Всю задачу вашу нужно разделить на несколько частей. 1 подготовить запрос POST в который нужно положить какие то данные( если нужно) например имя пользователя и пароль. 2 По запросу вам вернется в ответе токен. Его можно сохранить и потом прикладывать в параметре к запросу GET/ ПОчитайте POST GET Retrofit